# Yii - How to write validation rules for a CFormModel

Tags: php, yii

I'm new to Yii framework. I 'm using Yii framework for my application. Now , the data is extracted from XML file and not from database.The data entered into textfield is also converted to XML file. The model class extends CFormModel . I have a textfield that should allow only integers. I did a front end validation using Javascript that works fine for some browsers but not most. So, I want to do a backend validation using rules(). How can I write the validation rule for this to allow integers.
**EDIT**

```
if (isset($_GET['TestForm']['min']) && isset($_GET['TestForm']['max'])) {
                $test = $xml->addChild('test');
                $test->addChild('min', $_GET['TestForm']['min']?$_GET['TestForm']['min']:"0");
                $test->addChild('max', $_GET['TestForm']['max']?$_GET['TestForm']['max']:"500000000");

            } else {
                $test = $xml->addChild('area');
                $test->addChild('min', 0);
                $test->addChild('max', 5000000);
            }
```

**EDIT 2**
simplexml_load_string parser error is the warning shown

Comment: can you just post the code here so that we could see whats wrong with your code?

Comment: I think we maybe need to see your entire model, and the xml you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 1):

in your model
suppose the modelname is **file.php**
**create a variable**

```
public $name;

public function rules()
{
return array(
array('name','numerical', 'integerOnly' => true)

);
}
```

in view where form is created
here **$model** is the object

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is not working... I have tried the same thing..It shows exception instead of showing it as an error

Comment: what exception does it throw?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job

models/yourformmodel.php:

```
public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('field', 'required'),
            array('field', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
        );
    }
```

Comment: This isn't working...creates exception instead of displaying error

Answer (score 0):

Here is good documentation. Just read...

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/

Answer (score 0):

First the setup:

You have a classic problem, you want to verify that a user accepted the contract terms but the value of the acceptance is not stored (bound) in the database...  So you extend CFormModle, define the rules and got to validate.  With bound variables you validated as part of save.  Now you validate() by itself but Validate requires a list of attributes which is not defined in CFormModel.  So, what do you do?  You do this:

***$contract->validate($contract->attributeNames())***

Here's the full example:

```
class Contract extends CFormModel
{
...
    public $agree = false;
...
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('agree', 'required', 'requiredValue' => 1, 'message' => 'You must accept term to use our service'),
        );
    }
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
                'agree'=>' I accept the contract terms'
        );
    }
}
```

Then in the controller you do this:

```
public function actionAgree(){
    $contract = new Contract;
    if(isset($_POST['Contract'])){
        //$contract->attributes=$_POST['Contract'];  //contract attributes not defined in CFormModel
        ...
        $contract->agree = $_POST['Contract']['agree'];
        ...
    }
    if(!$contract->validate($contract->attributeNames())){
        //re-render the form here and it will show up with validation errors marked!
    }
```

[image]
[image]